# pkg is not defined when using Plugman

Tags: cordova, plugman

I'm getting pkg is not defined when attempting to sudo plugman createpackagejson {path of plugin} I can see there's plenty on Github about this issue but no precise directions on work around or how to fix it. Please could someone advise?

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue when using [keymob-plugin](https://github.com/keymobdev/phonegap-plugins).

This issue was fixed with [pull request](https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/pull/597) which already merged into master but not published yet,maybe it will be available with the next release of cordova-lib.

For now you can create `package.json` manually because the content of `package.json`  depends on `plugin.xml`. You can also  read the `package.json`  in other 3rd plugins and  the  [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json.) of `package.json` .

Comment: Rather ironically, it seems as though you haven't added your package.json file to github, so trying to follow your advice by looking at *your* plugin's package.json ends up as a dead end! ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's not working for me either. I've created it with

```
npm init
```

and manually entered the information requested.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been fixed. It stopped saying this error when I updated plugman using

```
npm install plugman
```

However, then it said another error. It's pretty poor practise that there is no effort towards making plugins backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this has been addressed, but a fix has not been released, yet. https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/pull/597 .